# Firefox and Chrome error when linking js-cookie: Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined

Tags: javascript, js-cookie

Error in the console log:  "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined"
This is what is causing the error:

```
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Does this happen to anyone else on Chrome and firefox? Does anyone have a solution?

This wasn't happening before, but started today.

Comment: `module` is node.js feature. It doesn't work in the browser. There are various technics to emulate loading `commonjs` modules but it's usually done with bundlers during build phase.

Comment: Oh, I am guessing since the CDN file used to work perfectly fine in the past, it's because probably the author changed the code to only work in node.js... Man that sucks. Thanks though

Comment: We just fixed the exact same issue by loading `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.0-rc.1/dist/js.cookie.min.js`. We've previously been loading `js-cookie@rc`. HTH

Comment: The code comes from js-cookie (I have linked in the post if you want access to the code it self)

Comment: @kissu but he wanted to show the error sign so it has to be posted as an image

Comment: @I_love_vegetables The image is useful to show that it is throwing an error but the code itself still needs to be in the question.

Comment: yep, but the codes in the image arent necessary to be posted in the question because it isnt the one causing the error right? it is the script tag which is already posted in the question (im just assuming it based on the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Major releases of packages can shift around files. In this case the referenced file became a CommonJS module, which doesn't run directly in the browser. The good news is that many packages, including the new version of js-cookie, tell jsdelivr which file to use by default.

If you use this url, everything should keep working: `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc`

Answer (score 12):

So it turns out it's the js-cookie's most recent release that broke things.

I posted the issue on their github repo and got a work around, until they solve this issue in their latest release:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/698

Elte156 said that to use this earlier version for now, until the breaking change resolves:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.0-rc.1/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

I can confirm that this work around works for me.

Comment: "until they solve this issue in their latest release" - I don't think this is correct. They have no "issue" on their side, they had a breaking change that will require modifications in the future. Pinning an old version will work for now, but don't expect that you can simply remove `3.0.0-rc.1` in the future (with any future release). See also https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/698#issuecomment-880466721

Comment: Yes you are right. And in the link you reference, it seems the author has added the correct link in their README.md for the UMD CDN release.